# Storing request values in OSB 11G

Tags: jakarta-ee, osb

I am using Oracle OSB 11 G. In one api call we are storing the values in an audit log. For that we are using JMS Queue which is called in response flow.

For this we need values both from request and response. Is there anyway I can cache the request values and use it back in response flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the request pipeline, just assign `$rq` to be `$body/*[1]` and you'll be able to use it later.